Como compartir ViewModel entre dos pantallas sin perder la información al cambiar de pantalla
tengo una duda que quiero saber cuál es la forma optima de solucionar.
(Uso Jetpack compose, dagger hilt, firestore)
Primero mi objetivo:
Tengo una screen que muestra con un lazy colum un listado de resultados obtenidos de firestore.
Cuando clico en uno de los items quiero navegar a la otra screen, donde quiero mostrar ese item pero al completo.
Y ahora como lo tengo:
Tengo un viewmodel que es usado por estas dos screen.
La forma en que lo he intentado hacer es, desde la primera screen, cuando clico el item, guardo todos los valores de ese item en el viewmodel en un liveData, y luego navego a la segunda screen.
Ahora en esta segunda screen es donde quiero mostrar esos datos al completo, y desde el composable observo esos datos almacenados en el viewModel.
¿Cuál es el problema? Que al cambiar de screen todo lo que tiene el viewmodel se borra ya que se reconstruye otra vez, por lo tanto no nuestra nada.

Justo hoy me surgió esa duda y así llegué a tu pregunta. Lo que yo hice para evitar que el ViewModel se recontruya es pasarlo como parámetro desde el Main.
val weatherViewModel = WeatherViewModel()  

composable(Screens.Home.name) {
    Home(navController = navController, weatherViewModel = weatherViewModel)
}

composable("dailyForecast/{timestamp}") { backStackEntry ->
    val timestamp = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("timestamp")
    WeatherDetailScreen(timestamp = timestamp, weatherViewModel = weatherViewModel)
}

Y así puedes manejar el ViewModel desde cualquiera de las pantallas.
